# Null checking object not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i'm trying to check for null value , even when i know the values are null the loop still doesn't break. Cheers for any help

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        warningMsg: 'No Warnings'
    }
    this.detail = {
        name: null,
        phone: null,
        email: null,
        location: null,
        extraDetail: 'Default' 
    }
}

handleSubmit(){
    const {DetailStore} = this.props;

    for (let value in this.detail) {
        console.log(value)
        if (value === null) {
            console.log('null found'); // i should see this in console but i don't
            this.setState({warningMsg:'Check Input'});
            break;
        }
    }
    DetailStore.entDetail(this.detail);
    console.log(DetailStore.getDetail,'Submitted'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`for..in` loops iterate over the *property names* of the object, not the *value* of the property. If you want to iterate over object values, better to use `Object.values` instead:

```
if (Object.values(this.detail).some(value => value === null)) {
  console.log('null found');
  this.setState({warningMsg:'Check Input'});
}
```

Comment: The for..of in your answer wont work.  You need 
`for (const value of Object.values(this.detail))`

Comment: @Jolleyboy your right, for of doesn't work. Thanks CertainPerformance

Comment: My mistake, objects can't use `for..of` directly, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The 'value' in your for loop is actually the property name.  You need to check:
`if (this.detail[value] === null)`

What you actually want is:

```js
const detailValues = Object.values(this.detail);

for (const value of detailValues) {
  console.log(value)
  if (value === null) {
    console.log('null found'); // i should see this in console but i don't
    this.setState({
      warningMsg: 'Check Input'
    });
    break;
  }
}
```